# WooCommerce shopping cart icon disappears on mobile

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

I read in many forums of a CSS workaround, but it did not help me. Been spending days now trying all sorts of things.

For me the shopping cart icon disappears when viewing on a mobile.

When I inspect the element then the code is following:

```
<div class="dt__mobilenav-right">
    <ul class="dt__navbar-list-right">
        <li class="dt__navbar-cart-item">
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="dt__navbar-cart-icon">
                <span class="cart--icon">
                    <strong class="cart-count">0</strong>
                </span>
            </a>
            <div class="dt__navbar-shopcart">
                <p class="woocommerce-mini-cart__empty-message">Cart is empty.</p>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

In woo-styles.css I have below:

```
header .cart-contents,
.mobile-header .cart-bar-toggle {
    position: relative;
}
header .woo-icon-count,
.mobile-header .woo-icon-count {
    color: var(--dt-whi-color);
    border-radius: 50%;
    -ms-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    -o-border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    font-size: 9px;
    height: 14px;
    line-height: 14px;
    position: absolute;
    right: -10px;
    text-align: center;
    top: -10px;
    width: 14px;
}
```

So I think I am close to something but have no idea how to execute on the fix. Perhaps someone with better understanding how CSS works can assist me and point me to what I should be doing.

I tried adding CSS below:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 420px) {
    .shopping_cart_outer {
       display:table !important;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your website online and if so do you have a link to see?

Comment: The css you posted has nothing to do with the html you posted. Why did you mention these rules?

Comment: @mehdi website is live indeed, it is https://www.rahvusehe.ee/ you can reproduce the issue when resizing window narrower. Thanks for looking into it.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

The .dt__mobilenav-right is the class that is displayed none when max-width:28.75em; As shown by devtools.
In order to keep it visible you should modify your css as below:

```css
@media (max-width: 28.75em)
.dt__mobilenav-right {
    display: block !important; 
}
```